# Java close TCP/IP connection

Tags: java, tcp

I need a java program to download a series of file from a web server and I need to be able to close and then reopen the tcp/ip connection between each file download.

Not sure how to do this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a low-level way of retrieving any information from not only socket 80 (http) but generically to retrieve mail, do a 'telnet' etc:

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
```

now to do a call to retrieve a page, send the get command, set the content-type, and send two '\n'.

There is a higher-level solution:
[Send HTTP GET request with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442791/send-http-get-request-with-header)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm looking for. Appreciate the fast response.

Comment: Just a follow up question. Once I close the socket and I try to use  it again (socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,80));) I receive a java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed error. I can't seem to reopen it. So I am just declaring Socket socket = new Socket();,Socket socket2 = new Socket();, etc... for how many ever files I am getting in the code. Is this the correct way or can I reopen the socket I closed somehow?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've coded like this, but from what I remember, the intention of this code was to make a stateless call (ie, get the data, then close the streams and sockets) and end the program (which I left out). To make several http calls, you could create 1. a socket object, and 2. an InetSocketAddress object.  Then for each call, just modify the fields of the InetSocketAddress (by calling some set methods on it), create a new reader and writer, get the page, then perform the close statements.

Comment: That's what I was thinking also is to just put the socket creation in it own method and call that method for each file GET. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Socket` for the IP and port you want to send it to, then read the file into a byte array using a `FileInputStream` and send that byte array through a `DataOutPutStream`, then when done just flush the dataOutPutStream and close the Socket and call the function again sending the next file.

Answer (score 0):

use the logic:
Please post something that you have tried.

```
 do{
      connection.open;
      while(!eof){
      fetchfiles();
      }
     connection.close;
     }while(no of files yet to download);
```