# how to add content type for httppost using httpclient?

Tags: android, http, url-encoding

1. Here i am using httpclient for getting response from a webservice, using httppost i am sending request , server data content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
2. How to add that,here is my code,means i want only "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" this type of data from service

   ```
   String postUrl = url;
           HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

           HttpPost request = new HttpPost(postUrl);


       request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       request.setHeader("Expect", "100-continue");

           HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
           System.out.println("ddddddddddddddddddddddd  "+response);
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(
                           response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
           String line;
           builder = new StringBuilder();
           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               builder.append(line);
           }
           Log.d("Response", builder.toString());
           resObj = builder.toString();
           System.out.println("ddddddddddddddddddddddd  "+resObj);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO: handle exception
           Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
       }
   ```

Comment: i don't understand the question.

Comment: i used  request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setHeader("Expect", "100-continue");

Comment: and so, i don't understand what your question is. you apparently set the header, yet ask about how to add the header?

Comment: i added that but it is not wotking

Comment: i am not getting data from service

Comment: means no data from service

Comment: and you know for a fact this is due to a problem in your Content-Type header? how?

Comment: possible duplicate -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442791/send-http-get-request-with-header

Comment: you post nothing to th server ... for x-www-.... use http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html to post something ... and dont you worry about Content Type ... UrlEncodedFormEntity will set it for you ... and one more  don't bother about Sharad Mhaske comment he is wrong

Answer (score 0):

i tried using the httpost with namepair values ,it dosen't work, so came to conclusion using other way

its working good,
**Note : we need java 1.7 jre**

```
    String param1 = "9880938687";
    String param2 = "value2";
    // ... 
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", param1));
    String query = null;
    try {
        query = String.format("mobile=%s&param2=%s", 
             URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset), 
             URLEncoder.encode(param2, charset));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    URLConnection connection = new URL(targetURL).openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);

    try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
        output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
    } 

    //InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
    // ..
    //Get Response  
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      response.append(line);
      response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
    System.out.println("***"+response.toString());
    return response.toString();
```