# Android HTTPGet to Rails REST Login

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I have a login that needs an email and password.

If I hit it from Postman rest client with this:

```
www.site.com/login.json?session[email]=bob@gmail.com&session[password]=password
```

The server (Rails) will read it just fine, like this:

```
{"session"=>{"email"=>"bob@gmail.com", "password"=>"password"}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"sessions", "format"=>"json"}
```

But, if I send in the same thing with HTTPGet from android, like this:

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //get the parameters
            String email = params[0];
            String password = params[1];

            String url = "http://www.site.com/login.json?session[email]=" + email + "?session[password]=" + password;

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

The server doesn't recognize the parameters, and I end up with an empty json object like this:

```
{"session"=>{}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"sessions", "format"=>"json"}
```

Anybody know how to form the parameters in this HTTPGet call in android to work like it will in a the rest client call? Thanks!

Comment: Does this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442791/send-http-get-request-with-header may help?

Comment: I have no experience with ruby, but have you tried encoding the email?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938420/how-to-use-httpget-in-my-app/17938774#17938774 try this

Comment: Why are you setting the content-type in a HTTP GET request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you have a typo in URL and params get messed up. This line:

```
String url = "http://www.site.com/login.json?session[email]=" + email + "?session[password]=" + password;
```

should be

```
String url = "http://www.site.com/login.json?session[email]=" + email + "&session[password]=" + password;
```

Note that I've replaced `?session[password]=` with `&session[password]=`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to send USER-AGENT or other HTTP headers for it to be valid?  Did you trace the HTTP connection with Fiddler2 or another HTTP trace?    That ? instead of a & is probably it though.

For a type-safe REST client for Android try:   http://square.github.io/retrofit/    It works very nice and you don't have to worry about manual parsing.

Answer (score 0):

One thought I have is that you could try encoding the query string of your URL.

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("session[email]=" + email + "?session[password]=" +                 password", "UTF-8");
String url = "http://www.site.com/login.json?" + query;
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
....
```

Answer (score -1):

* Replace the ?session in the URL with &session as its a mistake..

If the issue still persists, then try using a **POST** request as: 
 - in the first place exposing the email and password that way isn't safe practice 
 - and POST variables can be easily be handled in Rails controllers using the **params** tag eg. params[:tag] where tag is the key in the Json object.