# How to make an if-modified-since request?

Tags: java, android, xmlhttprequest, rss-reader

I'm coding a RSS feed reader that shows push notification each time the feed updates.

How can I do an If-modified-since request to the news site?

Comment: You can't do that. But what you definitely can do is to store the last modify date of your last fetch, and you can use a HTTP HEAD request to check that your feed is modified or not since your last download.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an "If-modified-since" header to the HTTP GET request.  For more information:

- [HTTP 1.1 specification - RFC 2616 Section 14.25](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.25)
- [Send HTTP GET request with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442791/send-http-get-request-with-header)  (Android)

But note there are some caveats:

- The server may simply not implement this feature.
- The server may not record a "last modified" time for the resource you are attempting to GET.
- The server's clock may be skewed ....