# How to use HTTP GET with Android?

Tags: java, android, http, http-get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do perform Http GET in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162260/how-do-perform-http-get-in-android)

I want to use the Google Products/Shopping API in my Android app but I don't know anything about HTTP GET. I'm  reading [this](https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/getting_started#products-feed) and it's giving me all these different web adresses to use. So how do I use the Google Products/Shopping API in Android with HTTP GET?

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to get familiar with [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) first, then with [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) and [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code where I get JSON from a server. It includes the basic code lines for connecting to something via HTTP.

```
public JSONArray getQuestionsJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {  
    // Making HTTP request
try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        String jsonData = reader.readLine();
        JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        is.close();
        return jarr;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```